# Setter and extended property same name

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm creating a class that deals with the `Audio` API to simplify some behaviors and wrap some functionalities that I want. One of the things that I need to do is, when `set` the `volume` value, I want the volume to change, but the point is that I'm extending audio API and `volume` is a value that already exists on that API.

I know that I can change the `set volume()` to `setVolume()` but this looks like a work arround and I'm wondering if there is a way to set that volume without this.

I try to make an "alias", something like `vol`, but with that alias I want to make `volume` as private and again I don't know if its possible to do this with and extended prop.

I try this too, but leads to a callback loop:

```js
class MyAudio extends Audio {
  set volume(vol) {
    this.volume = vol;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to deal with this keeping the default behavior of Audio API?

[EDIT]
One of the reasons that I want to do this is, since `Audio` API `volume` only accepts `number` as arguments, I want to sanitize string data coming as argument and set the volume with the parsed string.

Comment: I still don't understand the question completely. But from your code example. You have a circular call there. When you set volume `const audio = new MyAudio(); audio.volume = 100;` this will call `set volume(vol)` then `this.volume = vol` will run then in tern call `set volume(vol)` infinitely.

Comment: why not name it differently? `set vol(vol)` instead. and you can do `audio.vol = 100` or `audio.vol = "100"` and handle your `parseInt` in your setter as you want.

Comment: I can rename, but with that I want to prevent the access of `volume` outside of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to invoke the base class's volume property directly with `super` instead of `this`?

See example below:

```js
class MyAudio extends Audio {
  get volume() {
    return (super.volume * 100).toFixed(0);
  }
  set volume(vol) {
    const value = Number(vol) / 100;
    super.volume = value;
  }
}

const myAudio = new MyAudio();
myAudio.volume = "57";
console.log('MyAudio volume', myAudio.volume);

const audio = new Audio();
audio.volume = 0.57;
console.log('Audio volume', audio.volume);
```

EDIT: Updated to include executable code snippet.

Comment: That was a really good idea, but saddly the `volume` property is private so I can't access it directly.

Comment: If it's private, then you shouldn't be able to access it with `this` either.

Comment: I just updated the example to test it out. It doesn't seem to be a problem with it being private. There's also no mention with the API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume

Comment: Well I don't mention this before because its out of the scope of the question, but I'm using typescript, maybe its a ts limitation?

It throws this error:
`Only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword.`

Comment: I've checked on my typescript environment which doesn't have the same issue you are describing for me. `lib.dom.d.ts` has the following for `HTMLMediaElement.volume`: _Gets or sets the volume level for audio portions of the media element._

Comment: What are your ts version? I just try this on typescript playground and just works, but on my project don't, I'll try to figure out this. But thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to finish the question, the problem is that my `tsconfig` target was `es5`, I change this to `es2017` and works as expected. 

(I don't know if is a previous version does the trick)